# Django Polls tutorial part 2, Playing with the API section

Tags: python, django

I just started off with the Django Polls tutorial and ran into some difficulties in the *Playing with the API* section in part 2 of the tutorial.

As written in the text I changed the code in models.py to:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Now, according to the tutorial, typing in the shell `Question.objects.all()` should give back `[<Question: What's up?>]` but instead I still get `[<Question: Question object>]`

I do not really know where the mistake is as I am following the tutorial step my step and would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this!

EDIT: I left out a [step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO3lD.png) in the tutorial, which might be an explanation to my problem but the reason why I left it out is because I have no idea how to reconcile it with the first piece of code which I actually typed in.

Comment: Make sure you have restarted the shell after adding the `__str__` method.

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see `question_text` or `choice_text` fields defined in those models...

Comment: many thanks for your response, Alaisdair. Unfortunately, after restarting I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Comment: no I am using python 2

Comment: The `__str__` method that you have shown is ok. Please post your exact models.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of Python do you use?
add special **repr** method to your class like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Question: ' + self.question_text
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to override `__repr__` - Django models already a `__repr__` model which will include the result of `__str__`.

Comment: Strictly talking __repr__ should give output applicable to recreate the object, but I', not sure you need to recreate complex objects from string in django shell. So I think it's not so bad.